# What is the etymology of Wanona (said to be the name of Kullervo's sister meaning "weeping")?

Tags: etymology, names, finnish

Tolkien coined the name Wanōna (also Welinōre, Wanōra, Oanōra) in his [Story of Kullervo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011H55MNQ). It's totally possible they belong to Tolkien's constructed languages. But I think the etymology is still interesting.

*** Thanks to Yellow Sky's comment. Now that it's not a name in the original, the following older content isn't relevant any more. But I'll keep the *finnish* label just in case.

I came across this name in some [article**s**](http://www.mythsoc.org/reviews/tolkien-studies-7.htm) on Tolkien's works. *Kullervo* is a mythical figure from the Finnish saga *Kalevala.* The articles claim that *Kullervo* sister's name *Wanona* means "weeping" without adding a reference. All that I can find via searching "Wanona + Kullervo" are articles that are really about Tolkien's Legendarium, which raises some doubt in me.

It's known that Tolkien took much of *Kullervo*'s story into his Children of Húrin Saga.
**SPOILERS?**. The main hero, Túrin, married his lost sister Nienor unknowingly, and both committed suicide when they found out the truth. Same tragedy happened to *Kullervo* and his sister. Nienor's name is in one of Tolkien's artificial languages, meaning "Mourning". It'd be another interesting parallel if *Kullervo*'s sister is indeed called "Weeping".

But I can't seem to find the name *Wanona* in the *Kalevala* texts that are available to me. I know little about Finnish, so it'd be a hopeless task for me to look it up in Finnish sources. It looks like Finnish words for "weep", "mourn" are nothing like *Wanona*.

Comment: Tolkien [wrote his own variant](https://hergraceslibrary.com/2018/10/15/the-long-road-to-empathy-the-tragedy-of-oedipal-love-in-the-story-of-kullervo-and-the-kalevala/) of the story of Kullervo, in which he gave Kullervo's sister that name Wanona. The original Kalevala doesn't mention her name at all, and Finnish has no sound [w], it doesn't use the letter W in Finnish words.

Comment: It looks dangerously close to English *wane* (from Protogermanic *\*wanōną* (!)) and Latin *vanus*, but those words aren't Finnish at all.

Comment: @YellowSky Finnish used to be less consistent with using <v> and <w> was sometimes used instead. More relevant here though is that the 1888 Crawford translation of the Kalevala, the first into English, uses <w>. The Kirby translation in 1907 would still have been recent when Tolkien wrote his version in 1911, and given his own archaising tendencies, he may have deliberately chosen an orthography more closely matching the earlier translation

Comment: @YellowSky Thanks! I can't believe I missed that. I just checked out the Story of Kullervo book, but the etymology is still a mystery. Tolkien had several revisions with her name. Now it's even more unsure whether it's meant to be Finnish.

Comment: @杨Eugene - Yeah, it doesn't seem to be Finnic. The closest sounding Finnish word I've found is _[vannoa](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vannoa)_ ‘to swear/take an oath’.